# CMake: how to make execute_process wait for subdirectory to finish?

Tags: cmake

Part of my source code is generated by a tool which is also built under our main project with a `add_subdirectory`. We execute this tool with a `execute_process` command. Clearly, if the tool is not built before we reach the `execute_process` statement it will fail.

I use a GLOB (`file(GLOB...)`) to find the source files generated. I do this because it is not possible to know beforehand how many files are generated, neither their names.

How do I force cmake to wait for the subproject to be compiled before the execute process? I would need something like a `DEPENDS` property for the `execute_process` but this option is not available.

```
# This subproject will source generator the tool
add_subdirectory(generator)


# I need something like: wait_for(generator)
execute_process(COMMAND generator ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

file(GLOB GeneratedSources ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp)
add_executable(mainprject.exe ${ProcessorSourceFiles}
```

Comment: Use `add_custom_command` instead of `execute_process`?

Comment: @arrowd That doesn't work. Because I need to execute the process before running the command `file(GLOB ...)`. `add_custom_command` won't allow me to do that.

Comment: You can execute `file(GLOB ...)` and pass its result to `add_custom_command`.

Comment: If I run `file(GLOB ....)` before executing the process, the directory `src` will be empty. I need to run `execute_process` before searching the files (`file(GLOB...)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command `execute_process` executes its COMMAND immediately, at **configuration** stage. So it cannot be arranged after the executable is created with `add_executable` command: that executable will be built only at **build** stage.

You need to build subproject at configuration stage too. E.g. with

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
    -S ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/generator
    -B ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generator
    -G ${CMAKE_GENERATOR}
    )

execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
    --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generator
    )
```

The first command invokes `cmake` for configure the 'generator' project, located under `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/generator` directory. With `-G` option we use for subproject the same CMake generator, as one used for the main project.

The second command builds that project, so it produces `generator` executable.

After `generator` executable is created, you may use it for your project:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generator/<...>/generator ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
```

Here you need to pass absolute path to the `generator` executable as the first parameter to COMMAND: CMake no longer have `generator` executable target, so it won't substitute its path automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to model this with target dependencies. The tool "generator" should be a cmake target. In that case use [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/add_custom_target.html) instead of execute_process somthing like this:

```
add_custom_target(generate_sources ALL COMMAND generator ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src))
```

Then add a target dependency to "generator" using [add_dependencies](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/add_dependencies.html#command:add_dependencies):

```
add_dependencies(generate_sources generator)
```

This will make sure your target "generate_sources", which runs the tool will only run during build after the target "generator" has been compiled.

**The following is false**, see the comments for more info:

Use add_dependencies to add a dependency from "mainproject.exe" to "generate_sources". Now this I have never tested, so take with a grain of salt: With CMake more recent than version 3.12, according to the entry on [file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/file.html?highlight=file), you should then be able to change your file command to:

```
file(GLOB GeneratedSources CONFIGURE_DEPENDS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp)
```

Which I interpret as this will re-glob the files during build if the directory changes.

Comment: "Which I interpret as this will re-glob the files during build if the directory changes." - It will be rechecked at the very **beginning** of building, **before any target** is built. So `CONFIGURE_DEPENDS` option doesn't help in re-running GLOB after `generator` executable is built. This option is intended for catch new source files, **created by the user**.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Will edit. That severely complicates things.. How would we go about globing during build, though? My next best guess would be to run a cmake script as a custom target that executes cmake -P, have that perform the glob matching and write the found files to a text file. Then depend the executable target on that text file and read the file names somehow...

Comment: "My next best guess would be to run a cmake script as a custom target that executes `cmake -P`, have that perform the glob matching and write the found files to a text file." - Something like this could work, but only in "two-steps" scenario: The first build will generate source files, but creation of the executable would fail; the second build will glob correct source files, so executable will be created without errors. BTW, the globbing on the second build would actually be achieved with *CONFIGURE_DEPENDS* option.